# Excel vba-Populating cascading drop down based on values in another sheet with ids

Tags: vba, excel

How to build cascading drop down in excel macro vba code for the below scenario.

Main sheet has Business process,Sub Business process and activity name in which macro code is to be written.All the fields should be drop down.

Business Process Name and sub business data is retrived from the data in Businessprocess sheet.
Then the activity name is retrieved from activitysheet that is dependent on business process name or sub business process name as applicable.

Hierarchy is like this
Bbusiness process--> Sub Business Process Name -->Activity Name

If no sub business process name then
Bbusiness process--> Empty -->Activity Name

Business Process Sheet

```
BusinessprocessId | BusinessprocessName |SubBProcessI | SubBusinessprocessName
1                 |B1                   |NULL         | NULL
2                 |B2                   |3            | Sub B1
2                 |B2                   |4            |Sub B2
5                 |B4                   |NULL         |NULL
```

Activity sheet

```
BusinessProcessId | BusinessProcessname | ActivityId |  ActivityName
1                 |B1                   |1           |  A1
1                 |B1                   |2           |A2
2                 |B2                   |3           |A3
3                 |Sub B1               |4           |A4
4                 |Sub B2               |5           |A5
5                 |B4                   |6           |A6
```

Based on above 2 sheets the main sheet should have below 3 fields as drop down.

```
Businessprocessname | SubBusinessprocessName |ActivityName
B1                  | NULL                   |A1
B2                  | Sub B1                 |A4
B4                  |NULL                    |A6
```

Kindly help in writing macro for the above considering 3 to be individual worksheets in excel.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a consulting service. You need to try writing it yourself and then post any errors or difficulties after posting the code.

Comment: What have you got so far in your code?  Do you want someone to write this for you or are you stuck on a particular element?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question as to how to build a dependent drop down. I would suggest you start by looking at the following links:

http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/29/excel-data-validationcreate-dynamic-dependent-lists-vba/

The idea is to build a sheet with the co-relational data (and then maybe hide the sheet) and then use formulas in the data validation list box to refer to this co-relational data.

Hope this helps to start off.